# Javascript Animation trouble

Tags: javascript, animation

My code is for a website where when you press the movement button the two squares will move and if you press the change colour button both squares will alternate colours. The shapes do these actions at the same time. However, only one square does this while the other does nothing... please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: CadetBlue;
}
div#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: Maroon;
}
</style>

<style>
#containertwo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: CadetBlue;
}
div#animatetwo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 350px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: Olive;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>
<button onClick="myMove()">Movement</button>
</p>

<p>
<button onClick="button_click()">Change Colour</button>
</p>

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
<div id ="animatetwo"></div>
</div>



<div id="box" onClick="button_click();"></div>
<script>
var colors = ["Maroon","Olive"];
function button_click() {
    var box = document.getElementById("animate");
    var background_color = box.style.backgroundColor;
    var i = colors.indexOf(background_color);
    if (i === colors.length-1) {
        i = -1;
    }
    animate.style.backgroundColor = colors[i+1];
}
</script>

<div id="box" onClick="myMove();"></div>
<script>
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
</script>

<div id="box" onClick="button_click();"></div>
<script>
var colorstwo = ["Maroon","Olive"];
function button_clicktwo() {
    var box = document.getElementById("animatetwo");
    var background_color = box.style.backgroundColor;
    var i = colorstwo.indexOf(background_color);
    if (i === colorstwo.length-1) {
        i = -1;
    }
    animatetwo.style.backgroundColor = colorstwo[i+1];
}
</script>



<div id="box" onClick="myMove();"></div>
<script>
function myMovetwo() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animatetwo");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I'll talk about the problem you're having first, then I'll try to give you some advice.

1) First of all upon clicking the "Movement" button you're only calling the `myMove()` function which is only responsible for moving the `animated` div, as you select it with:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
```

So if you desire to move both at the same time make sure you're activating the right functions, since I imagine you wanted to call `myMovetwo()` at the same time perhaps you could do:

```
function move() {
  myMove();
  myMovetwo();
}
```

That way you would call `move()` and both calls will run.

2) Now about your code, you should really consider isolating the different aspects of your page, and by that I mean isolating CSS, HTML and JavaScript, you can do that using the `<link>` tag to import your styles and the `<script src="path"></script>` tag to include your javascript code.

The other advice would be to remove `onclick` from your html tags and get the click event from your javascript code.

There are some great sources to learn this basics concepts, perhaps codecademy is a great one for starters https://www.codecademy.com/courses/html-javascript-css/0/1

Cheers!